# Grab option value of second dropdown on change of first dropdown - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am building a currency converter with react. The dropdowns are structured so that the exchange rate is included as an option 'value' and the name of the currency is the option.

```
e.g. 

<select>
   <option value="1.1934">US Dollar</option>
   <option value="130.44">Yen</option>
</select>
```

There are two dropdowns, one on the left and one on the right. I am trying to work out how to obtain the current option value (i.e. the exchange rate) of BOTH of the dropdowns, when EITHER one is changed. This is in order to start the currency calculation by dividing one by the other.

So far this is taking place on the handleChange event. I would be up for any ideas as to how to modify this in order to get the values from both dropdowns? (I have thought about using refs).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "../../App.css"
import cc from 'currency-codes'

class Countries extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            countryCodes: [],
            left: '1.198',
            right: '1.198',
            leftinput: '',
            rightinput: '',
            rightmultiply: '',
            lefttext: ''
        };


    }

componentDidMount(){

    fetch('http://www.ecb.europa.eu/stats/eurofxref/eurofxref-daily.xml')
        .then(response => response.text())
        .then(str => (new window.DOMParser()).parseFromString(str, "text/xml"))
        .then(data => {
            const countryCodes = []; // define an empty array
            const cubes = data.getElementsByTagName("Cube")
            for( const element of cubes) {
                if (!element.getAttribute('currency')) {
                    continue;
                }
                countryCodes.push({
                    currency: element.getAttribute('currency'),
                    rate: element.getAttribute('rate')
                });
                this.setState({countryCodes});   

            }
        });       
    }

convertCurrCode(curr){
    const codeObject = cc.code(curr)
    const currName = codeObject['currency']
    return currName
}

handleChange(column, value, textname, text) {
    this.setState({[column]: value, [textname]: text}, () => {
        console.log('left: ', this.state.left, 'lefttext: ', this.state.lefttext);
        console.log('right: ', this.state.right);
        console.log('leftinput: ', this.state.leftinput);
        console.log('rightinput: ', this.state.rightinput);
        console.log('rightmultiply: ', this.state.leftinput * this.state.right/this.state.left)
    });
}    

    render() {       

        const options = this.state.countryCodes.map(
            ({currency, rate}) => (<option value={rate}>{this.convertCurrCode(currency)}</option>));
        return (

            <div>                
                <div className="App-column-left">
                    <p>{this.state.left} USD = {this.state.right} EUR</p>
                    <select ref="App-column-left-select" onChange={e => this.handleChange('left', e.target.value, e.target.selectedOptions[0].text)}>
                        {options}
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" placeholder={this.state.rightinput * this.state.left/this.state.right} onChange={e => this.handleChange('leftinput', e.target.value)}></input>
                </div>

                <div className="App-column-right">
                    <p>{this.state.right} USD = {this.state.left} EUR</p>
                    <select ref="App-column-right-select" onChange={e => this.handleChange('right', e.target.value)}>
                        {options}
                    </select>
                    <input type="text" placeholder={this.state.leftinput * this.state.right/this.state.left} onChange={e => this.handleChange('rightinput', e.target.value)}></input>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}


export default Countries;
```

Thanks,

Robert

London, UK

Comment: As others have suggested, use state for both the dropdown, As you are using react, its better to stay with React's api and do not touch DOM directly.

Answer (score 0):

Save default values of 2 dropdowns to state and when you change one of them you can always read the value of the second one from state.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you can only change one select at a time, why not store the values of the selects in state, and then retrieve them both when one or the other has changed? And then you can pass to a props callback or something like that if you need to expose both values outside of the component.

```
class ExampleComponent extends Component {

    state = {
        left: '',
        right: ''
    };

    handleChange(column, value) {
        this.setState({[column]: value}, () => {
            // Do whatever you want with both values
            console.log(this.state.left);
            console.log(this.state.right);
        });
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can use the handler like this:
`onChange={e => this.handleChange('left', e.target.value)}`

and:
`onChange={e => this.handleChange('right', e.target.value)}`

I'd recommend reading about React [state and lifecycle](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html).

Comment: OK brilliant, I have managed to set up some handleChange events for the two select dropdowns of the currency converter. (Please see updated answer above). I have set up some different variables that I am logging inside 'this.setState'. I wondered how I could use the 'rightmultiply' variable to dynamically set the contents of the right input field, under '<div className="App-column-right">'?

Thanks!

Comment: @RobertYoung ```<input type="text" value={this.state.leftinput * this.state.right/this.state.left} ... ``` Is that what you are looking for?